# ASP.net 3.5 layout issue

Tags: asp.net, css

Greeting,
I have asp.net content page that has more than 30 asp.net controls.
all the control set with style="position:absolute"

I know it is not good practice for ASP.NET web page  globalization using  style="position:absolute.

Now is there a way to convert my current asp.net page layout to be fit with most of the internet browser.

I read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95xdeeha%28VS.90%29.aspx
that explain this issue but it is really hard to go and modify each control.

In case there is no way what I should chnage in my control style propriety to make internet browsers understand the postion of my controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis issue is not specfic to asp.net you should just follow the standard CSS rules and conventions.

There is no automatic tool to convert absolute position items to use relative positioning.
You are going to have to change each component by hand. Best to learn how to layout elements using the margin, padding, float, left, in a relative position to their containing element.

As a first step you must really understand how the box model works see here http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson9.asp